# Testing with Jest - TypeError: cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, npm, jestjs

I created a sample project to write tests with Jest. I followed some tutorials.

I added a simple calculation function in a typescript file as below.

**Calc.cs**

```
 export class Calc {
    public add(num1: number, num2: number) : number {
      return num1 + num2;
    }
    public subtract(num1: number, num2: number) : number {
      return num1 - num2;
    }
  }
```

Then added a test file as below.

```
import { should } from 'chai';
import { Calc } from './Calc';
should();


let calc = new Calc();
test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(calc.add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
```

Then I tried to run the tests as mentioned below. Then I got this error.

> PS C:TestProject> npm t
>
> > typescriptseleniumtestproject@1.0.0 test C:TestProject
> >     jest
>
> C:TestProject\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\crawlers\node.js:49
>         names.forEach(file => {
>               ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
>       at default.readdir (C:\TestProject\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\crawlers\node.js:49:13)
>       at go$readdir$cb (C:\TestProject\node_modules\jest\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:149:14)
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15) npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Then I browse to that file which shows an error and it is mentioned below.

[node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\crawlers\node.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88uHd.png)

Comment: please edit your question and provide some code of your own

Comment: I edited the post a little bit and added the small code.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that can cause this error: check that you're inside of the correct directory.